# Безопасная отсылка пакета (Сундук с двумя замками)

Tags: php, шифрование, javascript

Как безопасно отправить ценность по почте?
Внимание, спойлер к решению популярной головоломки!

1. Покупаем сундук, покупаем замок.
2. Кладем ценность в сундук, надеваем замок на сундук, отправляем другу.
3. Друг надевает свой замок, отправляет нам.
4. Мы снимаем свой замок, отправляем другу.
5. Друг снимает свой замок и получает ценность.

Вопрос: какой из методов шифрования позволит расшифровать "через" себя?
Т.е. снять свой замок, не снимая замок друга (4 пункт). При реализации в лоб, разумеется, наткнулся на стену непонимания со стороны [mcrypt_decrypt](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php):)

Специально для тех, кто любит отвечать "это вам не нужно": да, согласен на любой другой метод, который предоставит аналогичную надежность. **Https** не прокатит: сертов нет.

Специально для тех, кто любит отвечать "это вам совсем не нужно": спасибо, ваше мнение учтено.

Comment: Зы: отредактируйте, плз, заголовок)

Comment: @knes

> Https не прокатит: сертов нет.

Так причем тут серты? ssl - это не только ценный мех, но и возможность сделать свой собственный центр авторизации в 5 минут. 

Я про что: ssl - это в первую очередь аудентификация, а не шифрование. Взламывая ваш код (если вы не знаете друга в реале и не можете его подпись подтвердить (нет сертов)), почтальон поступает так:

берет ваш сундук, вешает на него свой замок и отдает вам сундук, вы снимаете свой замок, почтальону - профит, друг без ценности.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В качестве замка используйте обычный xor. Его главная особенность - двойное наложение возвращает исходные данные.

А вот как сгенерировать гамму - это уже отдельна задача. Хоть в блокноте от руки единичек и ноликов нагенерируйте. Главное, потом ее не забыть и повторно применить.

Comment: Идеально. С генерацией проблем нет, нарэндомить можно много. Единственная проблема: придется постоянно менять гамму, именно потому что она мгновенно вычисляется. Но это тоже поправимо: в норме, в качестве ценности можно уже нормальный пароль выслать.
А защита от перехвата - это уже совсем другая тема.

Comment: ну так - нагенерировали гамму, сохранили ее, зашифровали данные и отправили. Через какое то время получили ответ, расшифровали и удалили гамму. И да, гамму лучше постоянно вычислять.

Comment: Насколько помню, такой метод известен в истории под названием  [одноразовый шифроблокнот](http://www.cypherpunks.ru/symmetric/otp.html) (например здесь).


    Недостатком является то, что шифроблокнот (то, что является  «ключом») равен по длине открытому тексту. А также самой большой проблемой является генерирование случайной последовательности.

Comment: равенство блокнота и текста можно обойти, наложив блокнот несколько раз со смещением (равном длянне текста, умноженном на кол-во итераций).
А для генерации случайных последовательностей можно и urandom использовать, это как раз меня не пугает: все-таки если кто-то сможет воспроизвести(если кому-то ВЫГОДНО будет воспроизвести) мою рэндомную последовательность, придется вообще переходить на серьезные, взрослые методы. Тот же https.

Comment: @knes, а вот подобные нарушения установленных инструкций (из-за катастрофической нехватки шифровальных блокнотов) привели к провалам нашей агентуры в США в начале 50-х (исторический факт).

--

На самом же деле метод со случайной гаммой очень хороший (при ее доступности и действительно случайности).

Comment: @avp, вы про оборачивание длинного блокнота вокруг текста или про использование "сильно ПСЕВДО" случайных последовательностей?

Comment: @knes, про оборачивание. 

На самом деле там шифровальщики просто не уничтожали уже использованные страницы, а использовали их повторно

(сами же гаммы, насколько мне известно, были реально случайными и поэтому их всегда не хватало (добавьте еще и проблему доставки материала отсюда туда)).

Comment: Если злоумышленних знает первый пакет зашифрованный первым ключом и второй пакет зашифрованный обоими ключами, то он легко узнает второй ключ, который сможет наложить на 3 пакет.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно асимметричное шифрование?

- Друг генерит 2 ключа: для зашифровки и для расшифровки.
- Тот ключ, что для зашифровки, отправляется тебе.
- Ключ для расшифровки остаётся у него и будет известен только ему.

Comment: Да, рассматривал. Применительно к описанному мной случаю это не совсем то: на JS я это не напишу.  Это скорее ближе ко второму пункту вопроса. Но тут основная проблема в большей сложности реализации на JS:)

Comment: Есть библиотеки js [вроде такой](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/). а в [светлом будущем](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) и даже немного в [настоящем](https://github.com/polycrypt/polycrypt) есть WebCrypto api.

Comment: Насчет "симметричного шифра" можно так в простейшем случае - у пользователя сервиса есть пароль, он подписывает  сообщение, на которое он положил собственный длинный ключ чем-нибудь типа  

    sha1(password+encrypt(receivedmessage)); 

Вы таким образом, зная sha1(password), можете убедиться, что это сообщение зашифровал тот, кто знает пароль, и снять свой ключ. Тут ещё один момент возникает - как вашему корреспонденту знать, что это вы с ним общаетесь, а не mitm, т.е. вас тоже надо аудентифицировать, обычно это можно сделать, выслав пользователю сгенерированный для него ключ.

Comment: В общем, используйте DSA-4096 и не мучайтесь. Аудентификация с запросом, как в ssh. Есть ещё конечно момент - mitm может подменить ваш скрипт :)